# How does a fungus protect itself from digestion by other fungi?

Tags: mycology

If a fungus releases its digestive enzymes outside its body, how does it protect itself from digestion? How do fungi growing nearby protect themselves?

I have tried searching this on google but couldn't get an answer.

Comment: Which fungi secret proteases?

Comment: usually they do not, but rather ingest via clathrin coated pits I think.  then the proteases are found in a compartment called the proteome.

Comment: I think you mean the proteasome.

Comment: You would also be interested in fungal autolysis or self digestion. Please refer to the paper "The autolysis of industrial filamentous fungi." PMID: 11958333

Answer (score 1):

In general fungal cell walls are resistant to whatever enzymes or compounds they are excreting to break material down for consumption. Conceptually, it is a little like your stomach lining being resistant to stomach acid. For a more detailed answer you may have to head over to your local university and find a Mycologist.

There is ongoing research on how fungi actually "eat." You can look up fungal endocytosis if you wish to research it more. There may be other mechanisms as Shigeta mentions.